# Excel - IF statement to find out if two cells contain same keyword

Tags: microsoft-excel

I need to compare text in two columns to work out if the same keyword appears in each.
For example text in

- column L can be `Operational A, Operational B, Operational C, Community 1, Other, Standard`
- while text in column N can be `xxxx Operational, xxxx Community, xx Standard xx`
  etc (the xxx's are other words).

So I want to work out how I can compare L10 to N10 (for example) and if both contain the word operational, or both contain community, or both contain standard, return "OK", if not return "Change".

Thanks

Comment: Do you know the matching words ahead of time?  Ie, are they always "standard", "community" and "operational" ?

Comment: You could use instr

Answer (score 1):

Assuming I'm reading this right, this should work:
`=IF(OR(AND(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("Operational",L2)),(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("Operational",N2)))),AND(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("Community",L2)),(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("Community",N2)))),AND(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("Standard",L2)),(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("Standard",N2))))),"OK","Change")`
Just change L2/N2 to the row reference you need.

Answer (score 1):

Another option uses `SUMPRODUCT` to check the list against L and N and only count cases where a word matches both.

```
=IF(SUMPRODUCT(IFERROR(FIND({"Operational","Community","Standard"},L1)*FIND({"Operational","Community","Standard"},N1),0))>0,"OK","Change")
```

This works by looking for each keyword in L1 and building an array of the character index of matches. If no match is found, an error value is stored in the array. So, if L1 contains `Operational A`, `FIND({"Operational","Community","Standard"},L1)` returns the array `{1,#VALUE!,#VALUE!}` because "Operational" is found at the first character index in L1, "Community" is not found, and "Standard" is not found. This search is repeated for N1, and the resulting arrays are multiplied pairwise. For example, if N1 is `xxxx Operational`, the result is the array `{1,#VALUE!,#VALUE!}*{6,#VALUE!,#VALUE!}`, which is equal to `{6,#VALUE!,#VALUE!}`.  If the sum is zero, no keyword was found in both.

`IFERROR` converts the errors in the array to `0`, and `SUMPRODUCT` sums the resulting array. If the sum is ever greater than 0, this is because a keyword was found in both L1 and N1.